# MapStruct - already defined mapping methods are not called

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct in our project and I have a problem with the reusability of the mapping methods, that I already defined and that are used in different classes.

I have this method in `StorageMapper`

```
    fun toStorage(storage: StorageDao): Storage {
        return if (storage.container == null) {
            toLocationStorage(storage.location!!)
        } else {
            toContainerStorage(storage.container!!)
        }
    }
```

but I cannot somehow reuse the methods, that are already defined in the `LocationMapper` or `ResourceMapper`, instead, I have to define these methods bellow

`abstract fun toLocationStorage(location: LocationDao): Location`

A added `LocationMapper` into the `@Mapper(uses = [LocationMapper::class]` and also add `@Named("toLocation")` annotation inside the mapper, but still, I cannot reuse it.

Do you have any experiences with that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't understand what actually hinders you from reusing your mappers… you'd just `@Autowire` them and call their methods…?

Comment: Sadly, that did not work for me...

Comment: So what does "did not work" mean exactly?